# jQuery Queuing Commands without Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, queue

I want a DIV to fade out, update its content, then fade back in as tidy as possible.

**Current Way** (http://jsfiddle.net/19czxx9r/2/)

```
$(".my_div").off().on('click', function(){
    $(".my_div").fadeOut(function(){
       $(".my_div").text("i was clicked");
        $(".my_div").fadeIn();    
    });
});
```

**Ideal Way** (http://jsfiddle.net/19czxx9r/1/)

```
$(".my_div").off().on('click', function(){
    $(".my_div").fadeOut();
    $(".my_div").text("i was clicked");
    $(".my_div").fadeIn();
});
```

I'd like to avoid the current way, which works, because I'll end up needing to nest tens of functions for my project.

Is there a way to efficiently queue the commands in the ideal way so they run after each one finishes?

Thanks

Comment: You can create and maintain your own [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/), but this is what jQuery is doing internally anyway. The latter cannot possibly work due to the async nature of the anmations. Can you give details about exactly why the first method would cause you to write 'tens of functions'

Comment: Hi Rory, example's tough but something along the lines of:
> Fade DIV out > Update text > Slide in > Flash > Fade out > Update text again, to go through a fussy UI notification process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always write your own `queue` helpers:

```
$.fn.queueText = function(text){
    var jq = this;
    return jq.queue(function(){
        jq.text(text);
        jq.dequeue();
    });
};

var myDiv = $(".my_div");
myDiv.fadeOut().queueText('I was clicked').fadeIn();
```

```js
$.fn.queueText = function (text) {
    var jq = this;
    return jq.queue(function () {
        jq.text(text);
        jq.dequeue();
    });
};

var myDiv = $(".my_div");

myDiv.off().on('click', function () {
    myDiv.fadeOut().queueText('I was clicked').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.my_div {
    font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_div">click me</div>
```

Comment: Does this effectively mean that .fadeIn() is just $.fn.fadeIn, and it's a predefined prototype bundled in with jQuery, so we're making our own text changing prototype?

Comment: We are just making our queue helper and attaching it to the jQuery prototype. Also, yes, `fadeIn` is part of the jQuery prototype.

Comment: Gotcha, extrapolated this to make one for attribute too - works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Just be extra careful with collisions of other jQuery prototype properties. (Notice how I used `queueText` instead of `text` as there's already a `text` property).